# Grant access to create database but not access to existing databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-administration

I want to create a user in SQL Server 2008 R2, who should not have existing database access but can have access to create new database.

Tried the following steps:

--Step 1:

```
create LOGIN TestUser WITH PASSWORD='testuser123', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
```

--Step 2:

```
USE master;
GO
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO TestUser;
```

After login successfully, I went to create database but getting an error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to create a database you need to log into SQL Server using a login that has create database permissions.

Security - Logins

and then You need to double click on the user id for which you want to give the access of create database.

Right click your login and make it a dbcreator:

[image]

You can have a look into [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: And also system stored procedure `sys.sp_addsrvrolemember` can do the job.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsrvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017